How to set up devices for Visual Studio Code for a Flutter emulator in 2024
I know this question has been asked 6 years ago but with all new versions things are changed, I guess
I'd like to use Visual Studio Code as my editor for Flutter development, but I don't know how to get the emulator going.
I've installed Visual Studio Code version 1.88
Dart v3.86.0 extension
Flutter v3.86.0 extension
Installed flutter in c:\development\flutter version 3.19.5
Added to the path:
c:\development\flutter\bin
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
Installed Android Studio version 2023.2.2 patch 1
Flutter doctor does not give any errors.
I created a virtual device in Android studio and fired it up
Open a simple "Hello world" project in visual studio:
void main() {
  print('Hello, Dart project!');
}

I run the app
According to the internet this should work:
"Make sure a target device is selected in the lower, right-hand corner of VS Code
Press the F5 button on the keyboard, or invoke Debug>Start Debugging
Wait for the app to launch
If everything works, after the app has been built, you should see your starter app on your device or simulator"
The problem is that in that bottom right-hand corner is "No Devices."
In visual studio code I also tried running the command "Flutter: Launch emulator" but this command is not available.
How do I connect a device? I can't seem to find more/different instructions anywhere.
Update: I run the project in Debug mode (windows pc)


When I debug, the output automatically runs to the terminal
UPDATE**
Appeared to be that the project I was using, example code from a Flutter book, was wrong. At least, I should have created the project using the command ''Flutter: create project'' Once I did that and used the example code from the book the device was visible in VSCode.
So, problem solved.
